# Missing Value in form when creating a table in phpmyadmin SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make a table but every time I type my sql code I get an error "Missing value in form". I am sure there is no problem with the code rather something else.

Here is my code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: query work fine for me.

Comment: Try it in another client,such as http://www.heidisql.com/ .I hear something about phpmyadmin bug.

Comment: try running it in a sql fiddle to check. phpmyadmin has bugs

Comment: How are you trying to execute this query? I just tested in phpMyAdmin and it worked fine. I go to a database and click the SQL tab, from there I pasted your query in to the box and pressed Go. It worked as expected. JohnRuddell and Mihai, what do you mean about phpMyAdmin bugs? This seems pretty simple, I'd be shocked if there is a unreported bug in phpMyAdmin creating tables. Seems something like that would have been noticed loudly and publicly.